Why is via breakout requirement more strict for class 3 board
I am designing boards for space applications. I want to use small vias to make breaking out a large 0.8mm pitch BGA possible with fewer layers. I have already designed and made prototypes of this board and the design works, but one issue always comes up in DFM reviews: they say the AR's are too small and I have to waive the class 3 AR requirement. My question: is this a very bad approach? Why does class 3 require zero breakout? Are vias with breakouts more likely to experience failure in demanding (i.e. vibration) environments? I don't see why even a 180 degree breakout is a problem. Once the hole gets plated, connectivity will be made. I could see it being an issue for a high-current path, but high current paths should be connecting to planes anyway, so the AR becomes irrelevant. For signal level connections, the plated via hole should make plenty of connection. Even if the via drill completely severs the trace from the pad, the plated hole would restore the connection. Please help me understand if my approach is likely to lead to latent failures once this board is deployed in demanding environments. Thanks for any input!

you can overcome the trace weakness to a via by using tapered traces like a teardrop.

You can overcome the trace weakness to a via by using tapered traces like a teardrop.
 source
You then need to verify your design on 5 test boards with Thermal shock +70 to -40 (dry ice) and random shock 15g or test to failure above Env limits for 3(?) sigma margin.  This is also an excellent PVT test for proving the solder profile reliability with almost open solder joints.
Depanelization stress is another stress on microvia-breakouts and brittle ceramic SMTs, so specify how that is done.
The small vias with long, deep holes might be mechanically weak due to their small diameter, especially in high-vibration environments. Breakouts can exacerbate this weakness. While you're correct that the via's plating should restore connectivity, mechanical failure of the via itself (due to stress or fatigue) could result in latent failure, where the connection degrades over time under vibration or thermal cycling.

This is a helpful answer. Yes, I do incorporate teardrops which is another reason I felt breakouts should be a non-issue. Based on your answer, it sounds like I am better off heeding the warnings and going with bigger drills and ARs to reduce risk of latent failures. I think this will push me from a 16-layer to a 20-layer design.. would like to hear a few more opinions before I mark this answer as correct. Thanks!

The quality of your PCB shop will give you better advice.
e.g. 2 microvias are much better than 1  and cheaper than 20 layers. You can also cheaply increase FR4 thickness for rigidity to 0.125" as the cost starts on total unetched copper plus overhead. Water-cooled mainframes were like this with 50 layer boards and fineline tracks in the '80's. very thick using 10 ton presses and immersion goldplating.
